# Will the compiler optimize away creating this list twice?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-construction

```
public SharpQuery Add(params HtmlNode[] elements)
{
    var nodes = new List<HtmlNode>(_context.Count + elements.Length);
    nodes.AddRange(_context);
    nodes.AddRange(elements);
    return new SharpQuery(nodes, this);
}

public SharpQuery(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes, SharpQuery previous = null)
{
    if (nodes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("nodes");
    _previous = previous;
    _context = new List<HtmlNode>(nodes);
}
```

I've got a whole bunch of functions that create a new `List<T>`, add a bunch of nodes to it, then pass it off to that constructor, which takes the list, and creates yet another new list with it.

Is the compiler smart enough to figure out it doesn't really need to create the list twice?

Comment: Would you please consider making the question title more specific? Question titles like this tends to cause duplication.

Comment: @Andre: Sorry was hard to think of a title that captured that info without showing code.

Comment: No problem. Much better now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a case of being "smart enough" - the compiler does what it is told; you are telling it to create multiple lists: it will create multiple lists.

However, since you release them promptly they *should* get collected fairly cleanly, hopefully gen-0. So unless you are doing this in a tight loop, I wouldn't get too excited about it.

If you want to avoid the lists, you *might* consider LINQ `Concat`, which allows you to append sequences without any extra lists / collections / etc.

Comment: How would concat work without creating an extra list? I see it works with enumerables, but I can't create an enumerable...?

Comment: ...Nevermind. Guffa's answer answers it. I concat to the context, and that won't modify the context, just provides an enumerable for it. Cool :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the compiler can't do optimisations like that.

As the constructor takes an IEnumerable, you can create an expression instead of a list:

```
public SharpQuery Add(params HtmlNode[] elements) {
  return new SharpQuery(_context.Concat(elements), this);
}
```

The `Concat` method will create an expression that first returns the items of `_context`, then the items of `elements`. When the list is created in the constructor it will use the expression, which reads directly from `_context` and `elements`, so the collection is only created once.

Comment: Note that `Union` is not the same as adding both lists, since `Union` is distinct; did you mean `Concat`?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Good point, `Concat` is of course what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

If you tell it to create a new object, it will create a new object. I don't think there is an optimization that would replace a constructor call with a cast and an assigment - the compiler must know way too much about what the constructor does to be able to optimize it this way.

Technically, you could do it yourself - `_context = (List<HtmlNode>)nodes;` - that's what you want the compiler to do. Or, better, `_context = nodes as List<HtmlNode> ?? new List<HtmlNode>(nodes)`.
But in either case the list might be modified outside of your class, so you must be sure it doesn't cause unexpected behaviour.

So far, it smells of premature optimization. Your code looks fine, and I wouldn't change anything before seeing an actual performance problem here.

Comment: Well, it's a library. I might not have any performance issues in my use, but others might. And it's more about learning how to do things properly than about micro-optimizations.

Comment: I didn't know you could cast an enumerable like that... but even if I can, I don't like it because it needs to copied to prevent modifying outside the class. Only in the case where it's called through Add() would I not need it to create a new one.

Comment: Well, you could create a private constructor that would take a list and store it as is, and a public constrictor that would copy the members. Then you could call the private constructor from Add() and other places where you control where the list comes from.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler (of JIT) can't optimize that. It creates two lists for you. The question however is, is this causing a performance problem for you. With performance, you have measure, measure and measure. In 98% of the cases, I think this code will not give any problems.